# Google Auth credentials not retrieved properly on Heroku staging account

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, google-calendar-api, google-authentication

Rather than storing a credentials file on the server, we opted to use env vars to store the required info:

```
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID
GOOGLE_CLIENT_EMAIL
GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE
GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY
```

And we're obtaining authorization for a `CalendarService` as follows:

```
scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"]
auth = ::Google::Auth.new_application_credentials(scopes)
service = ::Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarService.new
service.authorization = auth
service.authorization.fetch_access_token!
```

Every part of the process works locally - authorizing, fetching an access token, interacting with API, etc. When we deploy to our staging environment on Heroku, we can't get past the following error:

`Unable to read the credential file specified by GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: Neither PUB key nor PRIV key: nested asn1 error`

I had seen this error in testing so I know it can be related *either* to a missing credentials file (like the error indicates) *OR* to an invalid id, private key, or email combination (because I was accidentally replacing the private key with an invalid value). In that situation, the error message was identical.

We have verified that all vars match the credentials used locally - what am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you are setting properly the GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY variable.

On Heroku to set a multi-line config variable you need to run:

`heroku config:add GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY="$(cat private_key_file)"`

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I couldn't fathom that there'd be a difference between copy/pasting into the Heroku dashboard config - or setting it via `heroku config:add VAR="contents of string" - and reading the contents of a file.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to storing the key in a new file and using `cat` would be to use `printf` instead.

```
heroku config:add GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY="$(printf "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY.....")"
```